# Sending mail with Indy without using external server

Tags: delphi, smtp, indy10

My apps send emails using the Indy TiDSMTP client component.  In some situations however, the customers are not able or willing to set up SMTP servers and ports, usernames, etc, so I would like to provide a solution that sends emails without requiring anybody to set up anything.

I tried the TIDSMTPRelay demo but I need to enter DNS server IP address explcitly (and when I did this, it failed on "Project SMTPRelay.exe raised exception class EIdHostRequired with message ''").  I was hoping for an Indy solution that doesn't require the user to enter any settings - one that will work "out of the box" as long as they have access to the internet.

What else do I need to provide?

TIA,
R

Comment: Be aware that some mail servers on the other end may refuse the incoming mail if some checks (i.e. MX record, reverse DNS lookup, dynamic IP range, etc) fail. Thereby it would be better to "relay" through a mail server that will accept mail and forwards them to the destinations.

Comment: Do you mean like, hard code my own company's email server and authentication details into the app, and use TidSMTP (client) to send the mail?

Comment: You can resolve DNS starting at the root servers, no need to know locally configured DNS server IP address.

Comment: @Marcus Adams, having local DNS is requirement for standard TCP/IP, so root servers is clearly overengineering.

Comment: It's as overengineering as using your own SMTP relay server.

Comment: @rossmcm: hardcoding is always bad :) I just meant because of spam many mail servers performs checks to try to minimize it. What could look like a "rogue" SMTP server could be blocked. Using your company server as a relay could be risky (especially if you hardcode authentication!), and still mail can be blocked if a mail from somedomain.com is sent through mycompanydomain.com, because they don't match. It can look like an open relay or a compromised server. It could even end up in some blacklist. Your customers should use their own server, or one of their ISP.

Comment: The situation I am trying to resolve is where the users PC is so locked down they can't alter any settings.  How do apps such as MadExcept send emails without needing you to specify a server?

Comment: MadExcept requires you to provide the SMTP settings when compiling your project.  See MadExcept's SMTP setup instructions: http://help.madshi.net/madExceptSettings5.htm.

Comment: Yes, but I don't have the SMTP server set in my project MadExcept settings.  In fact ME doesn't let me specify the SMTP server if I have `Act as SMTP mail server` selected.  Looking at the transactions with Wireshark I see that ME makes a DNS Standard query MX to `mydomain.com`, (which I assume it gets from the email address `bugreports@mydoman.com` I have specified as the destination of ME's bug reports) and hence works out the SMTP server to use.  All I now need to know is how do I get Indy to work out the DNS server IP address from `mydomain.com`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to send the emails to the recipient mail servers directly. That requires performing a DNS lookup to retreive the MX records for each recipient domain. Indy's `TIdSMTPRelay` component handles that for you (by using the `TIdDNSResolver` component internally).

There is no platform-neutral way to query for the machine's current DNS configuration. That requires platform-specific APIs. Indy does not have anything in place right now to automate that, though I suppose it is not outside the realm of possibility in a future release.

The exception you are seeing is raised by `TIdTCPClient.Connect()`. You should not be calling that manually when using `TIdSMTPRelay`. It is called internally after determining which `Host` to connect to for each recipient domain. All you need to do yourself is set the `DNSServer` property, optionally set the `RelaySender` property, and then call the `Send()` method. Nothing else.

Comment: Thanks Remy.
[quote]That exception is raised by TIdTCPClient.Connect(). You should not be calling that manually when using TIdSMTPRelay. It is called internally after determining which Host to connect to for each recipient domain. All you need to do yourself is set the DNSServer property, optionally set the RelaySender property, and then call the Send() method. Nothing else.[/quote]
I was running the `TidSMTPRelay` demo example, which I had assumed did all of that for me once I had filled in all the fields and clicked on "Send".  What am I missing here?

Comment: Not wrong, just old.  In `btnSendMailClick()`, remove the two calls to `Connect()` and `Disconnect()` that surround the call to `Send()`, just call `Send()` by itself.  And you can remove the calls to `Connected()` and `Disconnect()` in the exception handler, as `Send()` closes the socket internally before exiting.  Other than that, everything else in the demo is fine.

Comment: Almost:) Compile demo.  Run demo.  fill in fields.  Check `Log SMTP traffic to file`.  Click on `Send Mail`.  I get AV at line: `IdLogFile1.Active := True;`.  Running the demo once with the checkbox cleared stops the AV happening from then on.